# Why the code is not producing the output as it is supposed to be in the logic implemented?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

> Following is My DataFrame column(predcition) in the value Prediction
>
> ```
> val PredictionModel = model.transform(testDF)
> PredictionModel.select("features","label","prediction")
> ```
>
> I have created a list as follows
>
> ```
> val listOfPrediction = PredictionModel.select("prediction").collect.toList
> ```
>
> The ouput of the list when I do listOfPrediction.foreach(println) is:
>
> [1.0] [1.0] [0.0] [0.0] [2.0] so on
>
> The logic I am trying to implement is
>
> ```
>  val header: List[String] =  List("ID", "predict_0", "predict_1", "predict_2")
>
>   var Id : List[String]= Idcol
>   var Predict0  = List[String]()
>   var Predict1  = List[String]()
>   var Predict2  = List[String]()
>
>
>  for(x<-listOfPrediction) 
>  {
>     if(x==0.0)
>     {
>       Predict0=1.toString() :: Predict0
>       Predict1=0.toString():: Predict1
>       Predcit2=0.toString():: Predict2
>     }
>     else if(listOfPrediction==1.0)
>     {
>       Predict1=1.toString():: Predcit1
>       Predict0=0.toString() :: Predict0
>       Predcit2= 0.toString():: Predict2
>
>     }
>
>     else if(listOfPrediction==2.0)
>     {
>       Predict2 =1.toString():: Predict2
>       Predict0=0.toString() :: Predict0
>       Precict1=0.toString():: Predict1
>     }
>
>     else
>    {
>       Predict2 =0.toString():: Predict2
>       Predict0=0.toString() :: Predict0
>       Precict1=0.toString():: Predict1
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> and then I am using the columns values to write them in a CSV file the
>   problem is every time the else part of the condition executes. Why is
>   this happening?

Comment: Would be much easier if you just use add them as dataframe columns and then collect into lists, predictionModel.select($"I'd",when($"prediction"==0,1). otherwise (0).alias("Predict1"),.....)

Answer (score 0):

your code contains lines like `listOfPrediction==1.0` which are always false because `listOfPrediction` is a list and not a number.

You should change it to `x.getDouble(0)==1.0` etc (`x` is a `Row`)

Comment: I have changed but still it is the same.

Comment: @RanaZubair ok, `x` is a `Row`, so you need to extract the double value somehow. You should check the schema of `PredictionModel.select("prediction").printSchema` to be sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

listOfPrediction is type of List(Row). [1.0] [1.0] [0.0] [0.0] [2.0] these are Row types. Row is nothing but array of columns, so use Indexes to access.
Use Index
if(x(0)==0.0)